# printf flush at program exit

Tags: c, linux, printf

I'm interested in knowing how the `printf()` function's flush works when the program exits.

Let's take the following code:

```
int main(int ac, char **av)
{
    printf("Hi");
    return 0;
}
```

In this case, how does `printf()` manage to flush its buffer to `stdout`?

I guess it's platform dependent, so let's take Linux.

It could be implemented using `gcc`'s `__attribute__((dtor))` but then the standard library would be compiler dependent. I assume this is not the way it works.

Any explanations or links to documentation is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The C runtime will register `atexit()` handlers to flush standard buffers when `exit()` is called.

See this [explanation](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Flushing-Buffers.html).

Comment: +1, good point, and _within main, return expr is equivalent to exit(expr)._

Answer (score 4):

When the program exits normally, the `exit` function has always performed a clean shutdown of the standard I/O library, this causes all buffered output data to be flushed.

Returning an integer value from the main function is equivalent to calling exit with the same value.So, `return 0` has the same effect with `exit(0)`

If `_Exit` or `_exit` was called, the process will be terminated immediately, the IO won't be flushed.

Answer (score 3):

Just to expand trofanjoe's response:

> **exit** causes normal program termination. atexit functions are called in
>   reverse order of registration, open files are flushed, open streams
>   are closed, and control is returned to the environment.

and

> Within **main**, return expr is equivalent to exit(expr). exit has the
>   advantage that it can be called from other functions

Answer (score 1):

From `man stdio` on my machine here (emphasis added), whic runs RHEL 5.8:

> A  file  may  be  subsequently reopened, by the same or another
>   program execution, and its contents reclaimed or modified (if it can
>   be repositioned at the start). **If the main function returns to its
>   original caller, or the exit(3) function is called, all open files are
>   closed (hence all output streams are flushed) before program
>   termination.** Other methods of program termination, such as  abort(3) 
>   do  not  bother about closing files properly.